# Converting strings to "Leetspeak" using loops and dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to generate a list of words converted from their normal spellings to "Leetspeak". I am having one last problem in my for loop since it cannot generate all possible combinations. I think I am lacking one more line to append these values to a list. These combinations are dependent on my mapping dictionary. Here is the code below to understand further:

```
mapping = {'a': ['4', '@', '^'], 'e':'3'} #dictionary for mapping letters
input = 'stack overflow' #Input string

#Convert string to list
leet_list = list(input) #This code creates a list with each letter of the string: ie: ['s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k']

#Main loop for replacing letters
for index,item in enumerate(leet_list):
   for key,value in mapping.items():
       if item == key:
           for leet in value:
               leet_list[index] = leet

# Return to string
leet_string = "".join(leet_list)
leet_string
```

**Output:** 'st^ck ov3rflow' 
**Expected Output:** 'st4ck ov3rflow st@ck ov3rflow st^ack ov3rflow'

Thanks, appreciate your help.

Comment: Your code assigns a value to `leet_list[2]` three times. *After* it has assigned the third value (`"^"`) it *then* computes   `leet_string` and displays it. Which is why the actual output matches the third element of your expected output.

Comment: If you want a large number of different results, you're going to need a container or iterator for each of them. Look into itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dictionary For Mapping Letters #
mapping = {'a':'4', 'b':'8', 'e':'3', 'g':'6', 'i':'1', 'o':'0', 's':'5', 't':'7', 'z':'2'}

# Input String #
input = 'i eat ass'

# Convert String To List #
leet_list = list(input)

# Main Loop For Replacing Letters #
for index,item in enumerate(leet_list):
   for key,value in mapping.items():
       if item == key:
           for leet in value:
               leet_list[index] = leet

# Return To String #
leet_string = "".join(leet_list)
print(leet_string)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).